# i want the timer to be restarted

Tags: vb.net, debugging

its a basic color picker
now when color specified in the if ladder is catched it plays a song
what want is that when once that color is picked again the song should play again
i tried using the thread; but it's not working
thanks in advance..

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
              System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
         Dim BMP As New Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1)
         Dim GFX As System.Drawing.Graphics = 
         System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(BMP)
         GFX.CopyFromScreen(New Drawing.Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y), _
                       New Drawing.Point(0, 0), BMP.Size)
         Dim Pixel As Drawing.Color = BMP.GetPixel(0, 0)
         CPpanel.BackColor = Pixel
         redtxt.Text = Pixel.R
         greentxt.Text = Pixel.G
         bluetxt.Text = Pixel.B

        If redtxt.Text = 0 Then
           If greentxt.Text = 173 Then
              If bluetxt.Text = 73 Then
                 AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "song.mp3"
                Timer1.Stop()
            End If
        End If
        Else
           Timer1.Start()
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after your color is picked your are stopping the Timer:

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "song.mp3"
Timer1.Stop()
```

The `Timer1_Tick` event won't be called again unless you are starting the timer again somewhere else. How is the color being picked - just by moving the mouse over a bitmap? It may be better to handle the click event rather than a timer tick event but it's hard to say without seeing more of your code.

Comment: thank you. But i also tried 'timer1.start()' after the if else ladder. and that's the whole code. i just want to restart the timer after catching the color as specified in the RGB value.

Comment: @NirmalPatel : Why are you stopping the timer _at all_ if you want it to continue?

Comment: if i don't stop the timer in the if condition then it would play the song at all. that;s why.. @visual vincent

Comment: @NirmalPatel : Unless the change of URL causes WMP to reload the file I find that very hard to believe. But then again that would happen when you start the timer again, so you would rather have to check if it's currently playing anything, and if it's not then change the song.

Comment: @NirmalPatel How are you initially starting the timer? Do you want the song to stop if the mouse is not over the right color? Which part is not working? Does the song play the first time a color is picked?